# bash/linux for loop doesnt work like i want it to

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, if-statement, variables

can someone tell me please why its not work?

the perpose is to find the index of chapterNumber

```
chapter_number_arr=(ch-01 ch-02 ch-03 ch-04 ch-05 ch-06 ch-07 ch-08 ch-09 ch-10)
chapterNumber=ch-09
```

```
     for chapter_number in "${chapter_number_arr[@]}" ; do
        if [[ $chapter_number == "$chapterNumber" ]] ; then 
                index_file_name=$index2; 
        fi;
     done
```

Comment: "why does it not work?" is not a narrow, specific technical question. What do you _expect_ it to do, and what does it _actually_ do instead? We aren't mind readers, to know what you want it to do like unless you tell us. We know how to read _correct_ code, but if it were already correct code you wouldn't be here at all.

Comment: (also, what's supposed to be setting `index2`? This code depends on it, but nothing ever assigns it).

Comment: When you say "the index", do you mean the _array_ index, so ch-01 maps to 0, ch-02 maps to 1, etc? Or do you want the 1-indexed chapter number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chapter_number_arr=(ch-01 ch-02 ch-03 ch-04 ch-05 ch-06 ch-07 ch-08 ch-09 ch-10)
chapterNumber=ch-09

for chapter_idx in "${!chapter_number_arr[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${chapter_number_arr[$chapter_idx]} = "$chapterNumber" ]]; then
    index_file_name=$chapter_idx
  fi
done
```

...will set `index_file_name=8`. As far as we can tell from the question, this is what you want (it's the index into `chapter_number_arr` corresponding with `chapterNumber`).

Comment: thanks its exactly the answer i was looking for